# Can anyone help me to upload an image to server

Tags: android, image, upload, byte

How to upload an image (as byte array) to server using web service, in Android ?

Answer (score 0):

for soap webservices you can use ksoap2. there is also a wsdl>proxy.java generator

Answer (score 0):

```
**To upload your Image to server, convert a bitmap image to base64 and then send the string. Use the below code**

Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, width,
                    height, matrix, true);
ByteArrayOutputStream baostream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
resizedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baostream);

byte[] byteArrays = baostream.toByteArray();
encode = Base64.encodeBytes(byteArrays);

**and vice-versa**

byte[] decode = Base64.decode(encode);
Bitmap bitmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decode, 0,
                        decode.length);
```